# Set framelayout margin and its children width, height and position

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I am currently having a programatically created framelayout with a imageview and a text view. By original layout is relative layout.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);

    FrameLayout fr = new FrameLayout(this);
    fr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.question_bar_icon);
    ImageView b1 = new ImageView(this);
    TextView b2 = new TextView(this);
    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mcq);
    fr.addView(b1);
    fr.addView(b2);
    layout.addView(fr);
```

Now i am unable to resize the imageview and the button, also m unable to position them, in the sence textview in the center and imageview in the verticle center and left positioned. 
I tried layout params, but not working, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the overloaded version of `addView` that takes a `LayoutParameter` as well in every case you are programatically adding a view, otherwise it is inserted to the `ViewGroup` with default layout parameters. (P.S. you can also control the order of insertion).

For example for the `ImageView` you wanted to be in the center of the frame layout:

```
int width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; //or whatever you want
int height= FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; //or whatever you want

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, Gravity.CENTER);

fr.addView(b1,lp);
```

Do the same for the other view, **and most importantly**, do the same, using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` for inserting the frame element itself into your `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked well, one last query, what if i have to set the margin, gravity gives the position, but say top-margin of 10dp?

Comment: Call `lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)` with whatever values you want.

Comment: Thanks Itai Hanski, Worked well, but when i add it into a loop, its overlaps and gives only the last view, say want 4 such structures one below the other, is there a work around? cant use set orientations since its relative layout, and setting topmargin does not work!

Comment: You can use the [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) method of `addRule`. You can read more about it in the link. If specifically you want 4 structures one below the other you should probably use a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation.